# find google api.js version

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api

i'm showing the google drive picker in the browser.
For deployment i would like to freeze the version of the js file included to prevent future uncontrolled conflicts.

In the webpage (https://developers.google.com/picker/docs/) just includes the script using https://apis.google.com/js/api.js.

I've found out that adding the querystring ?v= enables to load an specific version. 
However, i can't find out which is the current version. This info is not provided neither in the page nor in the js file. I couldn't find a changelog.

Do you know if the js file version is available anywhere?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, take a look at the code at the [link](https://apis.google.com/js/api.js) you provided.
This isn't actually a library. It's just a loader for the library.

Here is a text from the documentation:

> First, the Google API Loader script is loaded. It is instructed to
>   load the Google Picker JavaScript and the Authentication API when its
>   loading has completed.

When this code invokes by the browser, it creates similar request. You can see this in `Network` Tab in Chrome Dev.

[image: request]

**Loader**

At this [docs](https://developers.google.com/loader/) you can read more about loader. As you can see you can load any library, not only auth and picker. Also, there is a place where you can pass version you want to load.

But, in your case of `picker` library, [here](https://developers.google.com/loader/#AvailableAPIs) you can find available APIs and there is only one version for Google Picker API.

[image: picker_versions]